# Audio on Arch linux sometimes don't work after reboot

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, alsamixer

Sometimes when I restart my system the audio isn't working. When I run `amixer scontrols` I get this result:

```
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',1
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',2
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',3
```

On the other hand, when the audio works I get:

```
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture',0
```

I have no idea how to debug such a problem. I tried to browse for some solution but with no luck. I would appreciate any help.